# 100% Height Div with image in the exact middle - CSS

Tags: css

I reworded this issue so it can be better explained.

My question is... If class "Window" is a div that can grow in height based on the content that is loaded within, how do I get id "loader" to float exactly in the middle (centered height/width) of div class "Window"? "loader" should float above class Window's content. Hopefully I am explaining this well enough this time. Thanks again.

Here is the code below...

```
.Window {
   margin:15px;
   width:100%;
   text-align:center;
}

#loader {
    display:none;
    width:32px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

<div id="someid" class="Window">
   <div id="loader">yo</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to set a height on #loader.

Then, adjust its `margin` style to
`margin: -{H}px auto auto auto`
where {H} is half the height of #loader.

Comment: I added 32px width to #loader. I also added margin: -{H}px auto auto auto to #loader as well. It did not center

Comment: No no, you're supposed to replace the {H} with half the height of your #loader div.  If your height on #loader is 40px, then you replace {H} with 20px.

http://jsfiddle.net/BcSaq/2/

Comment: ok but what happens when there is dynamic content loaded in class window? Example by using the <br> tags. http://jsfiddle.net/BcSaq/4/ This pushes the box down. I need the red box to remain in the center. As if it is floating above the content...

Comment: Then you need to make the position absolute and add a left margin like so:

`#loader{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    background-color:red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -16px auto -16px auto
}`

Remember to change your negative margin values to half that of the height and width of  your #loader div, respectively.

Comment: Testing this will put the #loader div in the center of the browser page and not the parent .Window div itself. If this is the only option I have, then I can make it work but it is not what I originally wanted to do. Thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
.Window {
background-color:green;
height:auto;
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
}
#loader{
width:32px;
height:32px;
background-color:red;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.new{
height:30px;
width:30px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addContent(){
var add = document.getElementById("someid");
var div = document.createElement("div")
div.setAttribute("class","new");
add.appendChild(div);
}
</script>
<body >
<div id="someid" class="Window">
<div id="loader" onclick="addContent()">yo</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**Update** : check the updated code,hope this is what you want..

Comment: Display:none; is needed for jQuery to show. Originally if I set a height on #loader it would disappear

Comment: what exactly are you looking for??.. dint get your explanation completly??. have an example site/modlule that your trying to mimic?.. or use www.jsfiddle.net to try or give us a description of what you want >?>????

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BcSaq/  I am trying to get the red box to center in the middle of the green box

Comment: Remove the `<br />`'s and add something like `height: 300px;` to the Window, see how that looks.

Comment: @Treebranch there will be dynamically loaded content there. That is why I put <br> tags. View  jsfiddle.net/BcSaq/4